# Can't seem to connect to my Debian Mysqli Server?

Tags: debian, mysql

So I have a simple PHP script which I attempted to do something along the lines:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "PASSWORD HERE", "database name");
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT STATEMENT HERE") or die (mysqli_error($db));
```

to try something out.
But it won't make a connection to the database. The script is working fine as I tried it on a homeserver and so on, but it won't work on the vps, so I know it's that the mysql server is screwed up.

I'm using Debian 7.
I used

```
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get install php5
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and a bunch of php-* (* = different modules or whatever)

I tried:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then wrote in the password, and it worked. So what could be wrong?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: It doesn't print out any errors.

Comment: It should in your error log.

Comment: @jordanm I can connect to the server through my webserver. (like, I can connect to the remote MYSQL server through my own homeserver) But not using a php file on the actual VPS.

Comment: He asked you to look in your error logs for a reason... I'm asking you to do the same...

Comment: some basic questions: Is the database in the same host? Did you checked for the granted the perms in the database? Is mysqli php support installed correctly there? ... you seriously need to find the errors msg

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the php5-mysql package installed as well? This package (usually) provides the mysql and mysqli php extensions (make sure that you reload the apache configuration when you install new php extensions):

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

You can check your php configuration to see if you have the mysql / mysqli extensions loaded:

```
php -m
```

Or, to check and see if it is enabled in the running apache configuration, create a php file containing a call to phpinfo(); and check to see if mysql is listed in the enabled extensions.